# RHEL GUI offers Automatic Time Zone Option. Is there a way to set that option from console?

Tags: rhel, console, gui, timezone

[image]

As you can see the Automatic Time zone is off in GUI.
Is there a command to set it on?

Example: if Automatic Date and Time is selected to be off from GUI, it can be changed from console with:
timedatectl set-ntp 1

Reedit for better understanding:
The timedatectl does not work to set the Automatic Time Zone. The above command is an example for the Automatic Date & Time Option.

Comment: AFAIK, there is no way to automatically set your time zone using `timedatectl`.   The GNOME tool requires location services to be turned on. `timedatectl` does not touch location services.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. My question was if ther is a way to set the Automatic Timezone from Console. The **timedatectl**, was just an example.

Comment: I do not believe there is an easy way to enable Automatic Timezone (and Location Services) directly from the console.